# How to find an error with SSL inside a docker container [Solved]

Tags: docker, ssl, http-redirect

Im having an issue with docker and https connections.
The container is running apache and wordpress.
Apache is configured with sslEngine.
Host has ip 11.22.33.44 and my_domain.
Docker container has redirect ports = 30443 -> 443, and 30080 -> 80
All certificates are in a dir and are loaded by docker container.
If I try from any computer:

- curl https://my_domain:30443 -> it works

If I try from the host:

- curl https://my_domain:30443 -> it works

If I try from docker container:

- curl https://anyhost -> it works

If I try form docker container:

- curl https://127.0.0.1:443 -> it works

But if I try from docker container:

- curl https://my_domain:30443 -> it doesn't works.

Trying with openssl i have same result with next error:

139934076478784:error:0200206E:system library:connect:Connection timed out:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
139934076478784:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=110

---

Solved: It was the firewall.